# Добавить элемент по условию

Tags: javascript, jquery

К примеру, хочу добавить кнопку "показать все" ко всем элементам определенно класса, при условии, если его высота больше 200 пикселей.

Делаю это так
Создаю элемент. По нажатию на кнопку меняет класс для родительского элемента

```
let $showMoreButton = $('<a>')
            .attr("title", "Show more")
            .click(function (e) {
                $(e.target).parent().parent().toggleClass("show-more");
            });
```

Теперь пытаюсь добавить эти элементы ко всем необходимым полям

```
$('.element').each(function () {
        if ($(this).height() >= 200) {
            $(this).find('.buttons').append($showMoreButton);
        }
    })
```

Проблема в том, что код выше, добавляет ровно одну кнопку к последнему элементу. То есть, при добавлении к новому элементу кнопку удаляется из прошлого элемента и переносится в следующий.

Попробовал добавить метод .clone()

```
$(this).find('.buttons').append($showMoreButton.clone());
```

Теперь элемент добавляется везде где необходимо, но клик по кнопке больше не работает. Либо работает, но одна кнопка, либо везде, но не работает. Причем другие кнопки работают исправно, а вот добавить кнопку по условию не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var getMoreButton = function(){
 return $('<a />', {
  title: "Show more",
  text: "Read"
 }).click(function (e) {
  $(e.target).parent().parent().toggleClass("show-more");
 });
};

$('.element').each(function () {
 if ($(this).height() >= 200) {
  $(this).find('.buttons').append(getMoreButton());
 }
});
```

```css
.element {
 height: 201px;
 border:1px solid red;
}
.element a {
 border: 1px solid yellow;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.element.show-more {
 border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">
 <div class="buttons">
  Buttons
 </div>
</div>
<div class="element">
 <div class="buttons">
  Buttons
 </div>
</div>
<div class="element">
 <div class="buttons">
  Buttons
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Но почему именно такое создание элемента необходимо? Ведь остальные кнопки создаются как в моем примере, а добавляются обычным вызовом $(".element").append($button); при этом никаких проблем ни с копированием элемента, ни с событиями

Comment: Вы создали одну кнопку и пытаетесь её добавить в каждый, но в итоге вы просто из одного блока вставляете в другой. clone копирует объект, но не копирует подписанные на него события. Т. е. вам по сути нужно в цикле создавать каждый раз новую кнопку. Я этот момент просто вынес в функцию.

Comment: Меня смутило очень, что метод $(".element").append($button); создает для каждого элемента новую кнопку, но если то же самое сделать уже через each - то нет. Выходит два разных метода, с разным поведением, а называются одинаково.  Странный этот ваш JS.